# are these mappings one-to-one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So for b. I said that it is not one to one because 3x and 3x+1 both map to 3, and it is not onto because 3x which fits in the co domain has the pre-image 3x^2 which does not fit in the domain. I think I did that one correctly but I do not understand what C. means. To be honest I do not know what D or F means in that question

Comment: The preimage of $3x$ is $\frac{3}{2}x^2$, but why do you think $\frac{3}{2}x^2$ is not in the domain?

Comment: Presumably, in this context,$\;\mathbb{P}\;$denotes the set of polynomials $p(x)$ with real coefficients, $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I said it is not in the domain because P denotes polynomials of degree 1 or less so rx or r where r is a constant. I said it is not in the domain because the domain is P not P sub 2 which means polynomials of degree two or less. If the problem had said Psub 2 -> P we could say that it is onto

Comment: Where in your posted question did you _define_ $\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: If the problem is from a book, it would be helpful to provide a reference (author, title, page #).

Comment: that is just how it is defined in my book I assumed that was universal. Sorry if that wasn't clear, but would my answer make sense given that definition of P? book is Linear Algebra Gateway to Mathematics by Robert Messer page 223

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the notation. The set of polynomials of degree at most $1$ is denoted $\mathbb{P}_1$, whereas $\mathbb{P}$ (with no subscript) denotes the set of all polynomials $p(x)$ with coefficients in the base field.

Comment: ah ok maybe... part a) of this question was P sub 3 -> P sub 3 so I just assumed that it was P sub 1

Comment: See page $44$.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comments,

> Presumably, in this context,$\;\mathbb{P}\;$denotes the set of polynomials $p(x)$ with real coefficients, $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Then for $(b)$, regarding $D$ as a function from $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathbb{P}$ . . .
$\\[8pt]$

- Is $D$ one-to-one?$\\[12pt]$

    As you correctly observed,
    $D$
    is not one-to-one. Your example is fine, but even simpler, note that any constant polynomial maps to the zero polynomial.

  $\\$

  Is $D$ onto?$\\[12pt]$

    Any polynomial
    $p\in\mathbb{P}$
    has an antiderivative
    $P$
    which is also in
    $\mathbb{P}$
    , so we get
    $P'=p$
    . It follows
    $D$
    is onto.

  $\\$

and for $(c)$, regarding $D$ as a function from $\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$ . . .$\\[8pt]$

- Is $D$ one-to-one?$\\[13pt]$

    $D$
    is not one-to-one, since for example, any constant function maps to the zero function.

  $\\$

  Is $D$ onto?$\\[13pt]$

    Let
    $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
    be defined by
    $$
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
    {\large{\frac{1}{x}}}&\text{if}\;x > 0\\[6pt]
    \;0&\text{if}\;x \le 0\\
    \end{cases}
    $$
    and suppose
    $F'=f$
    , for some
    $F\in\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R})$
    .
    But then we would have 
    $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=F(1)-F(0)$$
    contradiction, since the LHS of the above evaluates to $\infty$.

    It follows that $D$ is not onto.